# C++ remove & replace in a vector

Tags: c++, replace, removeclass

I have a vector of vector like this:

a: 0 1 0

b: 1 0 1

c: 0 1 1

This part of my programm works. After I want to delete the 0 so I use remove_if and  I want to replace the 1 by t and the position so I use replace_if for finally have something like

a: t2

b: t1, t3

c: t2, t3

These 2 things doesn't work on my program and I don't have idea anymore. I think one of the problem is that I want to have the "t" in a int but I don't know if I can use a string for this or not.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

     int main (){
    srand(time(0));
    int e = (rand() % 10) + 3;
    int tim = (rand() % 10) +1 ;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > myvector;
    std::cout << "Time: 0 = Not available, 1 = available" << std::endl;

    for(int vec = 0; vec < e; vec++){
            std::vector<int> newVector(tim);
            for(int i = 0; i < tim; i++){
                    newVector[i] = (rand() % 2);
            }
            myvector.push_back(newVector);
            std::cout << "The Time " << (vec+1) << " is ";
            for(int b = 0; b < tim; b++){
                    int value = myvector[vec][b];
                    std::cout << " " << value << " ";
            }
    }
    //Delete the 0 in time
    int int_to_remove = 0;
    remove_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), int_to_remove);
    std::cout << "The new Time "<< std::endl;
    copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), output);

    //Change the name of 1 to t1
    int int_to_replace = 1;
    replace_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), int_to_replace, t(tim));
    std::cout << "The new Time"<< std::endl;
    copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), output);

    return 0;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show us a _complete_ example. The code in your question is missing things, like `output` and `t`.

Comment: Do you just want to **show** a `t` in the printed output, or do you want to have a vector of elements whose value is actually `"t1"`, `"t2"`, etc.? If you want such a collection, then the elements must be strings. Integers are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a couple of mistakes up there. If you just want a leading `t` to be printed to the output, below I am showing how you should rewrite the relevant part of your code. Notice, that even if you do actually want a container of elements whose value has a leading `t` (and in this case, it must be a container of `string`s), the part which removes an element and the part which replaces an element in your original code are incorrect.

Here is how you should rewrite the relevant part:

```
#include <algorithm>   // For copy(), replace(), erase(), and for_each()
#include <iterator>    // For ostream_iterator

// ...

int main () {

// ...

    //Delete the 0 in time
    int int_to_remove = 0;
    std::cout << "The new Time "<< std::endl;
    for_each(begin(myvector), end(myvector), [=] (std::vector<int>& v)
    {
        v.erase(remove(begin(v), end(v), int_to_remove), end(v));
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^^
    //  If you don't do the above, your container won't be resized,
    //  and will have trailing "dead" elements. Moreover, if you
    //  use remove_if() with a predicate which is always equal to 0,
    //  you won't remove any element.

        copy(begin(v), end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                         This is how you can copy each element to the
    //                         standard output.

        std::cout << std::endl;
    });

    //Change the name of 1 to t1
    int int_to_replace = 1;
    std::cout << "The new Time "<< std::endl;
    for_each(begin(myvector), end(myvector), [=] (std::vector<int>& v)
    {
        // This does the replacement. Again, using replace_if() is wrong,
        // because you are not passing in a predicate, but a value.
        replace(begin(v), end(v), int_to_replace, tim);

        // This prints each element of the vector with a leading 't'
        for_each(begin(v), end(v), [] (int i)
        {
            std::cout << "t" << i << " ";
        });

        std::cout << std::endl;
    });

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector of vector of strings instead of int, since you need string values such as t1. i.e. replace

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > myvector;
```

with

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > myvector;
```

To assign string "0" and "1", you could replace
newVector[i] = (rand() % 2);
by

```
if(rand() % 2)
  newVector[i] = "1";
else
  newVector[i] = "0";
```

You will need to change the rest of the integer comparisons with the string comparison operator [std::string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

Comment: I don't understand if I use a string I need to change everything and can't use the replace and remove?

Comment: The main change will be the comparison operation. If you need 't' in the result, you have no option but to use string.